# contact of the editor

Tags: phd, student-exchange

I sent an article it's been almost 4 months, but still my article is in the same status "submissions being processed", that I have to do is what I contact the editor or I wait for their response, since I have heard when we send an e-mail to the editor, he sends the refusal directly, I wait for your suggestions, thank you in advance

Comment: _I have heard when we send an e-mail to the editor, he sends the refusal directly_ — If that happens, consider yourself lucky.  You've been rejected by an unethical journal, so you're free to submit elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Contact the editor. It happened to me once that the referees were divided, so the editor sent the paper to more referees, hence prolonging the process. He just forgot to notify me. Moving to another journal is a bad decision, since you haven't been rejected yet. What if then you are liaising with two journals and both accept it? **Not good**.

Also, check the average processing time of the journal. Some do take long time, even up to six months!

Comment: thank you very much for answering, the average time to answer is 76 days, in my case this time is exceeded, do you have a model of a letter to sent to the editor, thank you very much

Comment: @lilia there is no need to be very formal. Just respectful. They have gone well over the average time, so you have all the right to be genuinely concerned. Asking the editor for updates on the status of the submission is fine in my experience.

Answer (score -3):

Move to another journal. You should have done that a while ago.

Comment: must I cancel the first submission before sending it to another journal?

Comment: Yes.  If you want to submit elsewhere, you must withdraw your first submission.

Comment: Yeah that would be part of "moving" as opposed to "duplicate publishing".  Of course.  But all you need to do is send an email cancelling it.

Comment: The rationale for moving is NOT because of waiting for decision but because of no response to questions and in fact a status that says the thing has not even moved to review yet.